# StopPropogation based on conditions in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've onClick event for a div and based on elementType I'm performing some function, if it doesnt match the elementType I'm trying to stop using stopPropogation.But it does'nt work.Is there any way to fix?

```
  handleClick(eventDate , e) {
    if(this.props.eventType === 'DayEvent'){
      this.props.onBarClick(eventDate );
    }
    else{
      console.log(e,'e');
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

<div className="event-class" onClick={() => this.handleClick(value.evenTime)}>
          <div className="o-percentage">Hellloo</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` won't work. Because `divs` never have their default propagation. `return false` would do your job

Comment: @Manoj , Could you please suggest some other way to implement it?

Comment: You can try with adding the 'role = button' for the div you have onClick function on.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default behaviour of clicking on a div. It is unclear what are you trying to prevent?

Also `event.stopPropagation()` is to stop the event from bubbling up ancestors and triggering their event handlers.

> **event.stopPropagation()** - Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the
>   event

see more https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

What you can do is return `false`

```
  handleClick(eventDate , e) {
    if(this.props.eventType === 'DayEvent'){
      this.props.onBarClick(eventDate );
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

see this example I made for you

https://jsfiddle.net/kksnmnwL/1/

Comment: Great it worked.Yes,I was not aware of stopPropogation doesn't work from div tags.Thank you.!

Comment: Not just `divs` but all those DOM elements which don't have their default behavior. Like anchor tag by default redirects you to some url, there you could you stopPropagation by restricting it from going to that url.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like:

```
handleClick(eventDate , e) {
    if(this.props.eventType === 'DayEvent'){
        this.props.onBarClick(eventDate );
    }
    else {
        e.persist();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```